# Sort data by title in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

how can i sort my data by title? This is my code:
And how can i call this 3 calls at the same time? I tried with "Promise All" but didn't work for me..
Thanks for help! ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import './Style.css';

class PostList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: [],
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: result.data,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Please wait...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div> <table style={{ width: '100%'}}>
        
          {data.items.map(item => (
            <div>
            
              <tr>
                <th>Title:</th> <td>{item.title}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Artist:</th> <td>{item.artist}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Label:</th> <td>{item.label}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Year:</th> <td>{item.year}</td>
                </tr>
            </div>
          ))}
        
        </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}



 



export default PostList
```

AND

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';

class index extends Component {
  render () {
      return (
          <div style={{
            display: 'inline-flex'
          }}>
          
          <PostList url={"https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list1"} />
          <PostList url={"https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list2"} />
          <PostList url={"https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list3"} />

      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default index;
```

Comment: You've `data` state that's an array, and `items` state that's an array. What would `data.items` be? `data.items.map` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the items just use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare the titles:

```js
const sortedItems = data.items.sort((item1, item2) => item1.title.localeCompare(item2.title));

// and then render sorted items
{sortedItems.map(item => (...)}
```

---

If you want to do three calls at the same time you really need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It can be done in parent component, or inside of `PostList`. So you can do the following:

```js
const LIST_URLS = [
  'https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list1',
  'https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list2',
  'https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list3'
];
...
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  try {
    const lists = await Promise.all(LIST_URLS.map((url) => {
      return fetch(this.props.url).then(res => res.json());
    });
    const list = lists.flat();
    const sortedList = data.items.sort((item1, item2) => item1.title.localeCompare(item2.title));
    this.setState({ list: sortedList });
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({ error });
  } finally {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }
}

render() {
  // here you can just render single list with all the items, passing them as a prop
  const { isLoading, error, items } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && 'Loading...'}
      {items && <PostList list={this.state.list} />}
      {error && 'Failed to fetch'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but is not working. I need to modify a lot of code and i have some errors.

Comment: In this case you can pass urls to `PostList` component, like so `<PostList urls={[url1, url2, url3]} />` and use the logics I've written above to PostList component. Just update this line of code `const lists = await Promise.all(this.props.urls.map((url) => {`

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 API data should be sorted, then you have to use like below. If you want individual API responses to be sorted use sort before updating the state.

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: [],
      items: [],
    };

    this.callAPi = this.callAPi.bind(this);
  }

  callAPi(url) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: [...result.data].sort((item1, item2) =>
              item1.title.localeCompare(item2.title)
            ),
            items: [...result.items].sort((item1, item2) =>
              item1.title.localeCompare(item2.title)
            ),
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error,
          });
        }
      );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(props.urls.map(this.callAPi));
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Please wait...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            {data.items.map((item) => (
              <div>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title:</th> <td>{item.title}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Artist:</th> <td>{item.artist}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Label:</th> <td>{item.label}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Year:</th> <td>{item.year}</td>
                </tr>
              </div>
            ))}
          </table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

USE

```
<PostList
  urls={[
    "https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list1",
    "https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list2",
    "https://api.netbet.com/development/randomFeed?website=casino&lang=eu&device=desktop&source=list3",
  ]}
/>;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help but i have this error: https://nimb.ws/u8YApF